# how delete blob element from database in sqllite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i doing like these it not deleting blob element?

```
 public void favoriteDelete(byte[] byteArray)
         {

           database.execSQL("DELETE FROM FavoriteData"+" where Image='"+byteArray+"';");

        }
```

what i want to do to delete blob element from database in android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delete method from [android.database.sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)